# Send Fluentd logs to another Fluentd installed in another machine : failed to flush the buffer error="no nodes are available"

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to send the logs from fluentd to another fluentd, both are installed in two different machines (ubuntu) that I get access to through PuTTy.

The match clause of Fluentd.conf of log forwarder is the following :

```
<source>
 @type tail
 path /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/*.gz
 pos_file /var/log/td-agent/httpd-access.log.pos
 tag apache.access
 format apache2
</source>

<match **>
 @type copy
 <store>
  @type forward
  @id forward_output
  heartbeat_type tcp
  <server>
   host private_ip_addr
   port 24224
  </server>
  flush_interval 1s
 </store>
 <store>
  @type stdout
 </store>
</match>
```

To test if the logs are pulled properly I tried sending them to a local directory, and I did find them so source section works well.
I can ping the machines.
the fluentd.conf of log aggregator is the following :

```
<source>
 @type forward
 @id forward_input
 port 24224
</source>
<match **>
 @type stdout
</match>
```

I get ping the machines using the private IP adresse.
I've been trying for a while, some help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you see any warnings or errors in the first fluetd logs? You  using tag `apache.access` but in `<match>` section the tag is `debug.**`. The tags don't match. Change `<match debug.**>` to `<match apache.access>` and then try again.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/config-file#2.-match-tell-fluentd-what-to-do

Comment: @Azeem I didn't have any errors or warnings, I changed the match but I still didn't find the logs in the other machine.

Comment: Right. And, no errors even after `flush_interval 10s`?

Comment: For testing, comment all the match section configuration and use `@type stdout` only. See if it prints any logs on the screen.

Comment: @Azeem I tried sending them to a local directory, and I did find them so source section works well. The problem is when sending them to Fluentd. The last line of the output of compilation is : 
2022-04-14 11:18:10 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
 And after two minutes I get this warning : 2022-04-14 11:20:22 +0000 [warn]: #0 detached forwarding server '' host="***" port=24224 hard_timeout=true

Comment: Please add both configurations in your question. I'd like to reproduce it on my side.

Comment: @Azeem I added both configurations to the question

Comment: Thanks! What is this output plugin `@type secondary_file`?

Comment: At first, I added @type file , but then output of compilation suggested to change it to secondary_file so I did so. I think because it's on secondary section and the output would be stored in a directory. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "compilation" here? The `<secondary>` section should contain an output plugin e.g. file. By default, there's no `secondary_file` output plugin as part of its core. More details here: https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output#secondary-output.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the same scenario on the same machine and it's working fine.

> fluentd 1.14.6

---

**fluent1.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type sample
  tag test
</source>

<match test>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type forward
    <server>
      host localhost
    </server>
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

Run:

```sh
fluentd -c fluent1.conf
```

---

**fluent2.conf**

```xml
<source>
  @type forward
  tag test
</source>

<match test>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Run:

```sh
fluentd -c fluent2.conf
```

---

**Demo**

[image: demo]

Comment: I did run your code, fluent1.conf works well but fluent2.conf doesn't, I get the following :

Comment: @issrae: Error?

Comment: I did run your code, fluent1.conf works well when I add <match ** (not test)>. But fluent2.conf doesn't, I only get warning :  parameter 'tag' in <source> is not used , and the following : 2022-04-15 12:28:23.676399466 +0000 fluent.info: {"worker":0,"message":"fluentd worker is now running worker=0"} ((not followed by the logs)). I'm not sure why the same code doesn't work in my machine.

Comment: @issrae: What is your fluentd version? Ignore the warning. You have to run both fluentd instances in separate terminals. Run `fluent2.conf ` first, otherwise you'll get connection errors for `fluent1.conf`.

Comment: Yes I did run them in seperate terminals (a script on machine that sends the logs and the other on the machine that receives them). I installed the last version of fluentd. (in the machine that receives log it's installed as a docker image, and the another using gem)

Comment: @issrae: Are you able to `ping` these machines from their terminals? Are they both on the same network?

Comment: @issrae: BTW, the above example is meant to run on the same machine. Observe `host localhost`. You need to configure IP or hostname accordingly.

Comment: I'm not able to ping, they're both different virtual machines that I access to using putty. Yes I changed localhost to IP adresse of the other machine that I'll send logs to.

Comment: @issrae: That sounds like a network issue, not `fluentd` issue per se. You need to make sure that both machines are reachable. Even if `ping` is not working, you should be able to use `telnet`. See this troubleshooting section: https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output/forward#troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes right it seems so, I'll check it out thank you!

Comment: I can ping the two machines but the logs still aren't received, and now I get : failed to flush the buffer error="no nodes are available". I edited the question with the scripts used.

Comment: @issrae: Please add the complete details of your machines and both configurations. Also, please test with `telnet` also. See if TCP connection is working from source to destination.

Comment: I tested with telnet, I get : Trying ip_addr...  Connected to ip_addr.  Escape character is '^]'. So i think it's working.
Also,for the ping is works with the private ip address. But when i did : curl http://0.0.0.0:24224 I get the connection is refused. so I'm assuming this is the problem.  I did add the details to the question, if it's missing something please tell me so that'll give more informations.

Comment: @issrae: `telnet` from the source machine to the destination machine? Like this `telnet <ip-addr> 24224`?. In your second configuration above, you have to add the `host <pubic-ip-addr>` so that it's visible to your source machine.

Comment: Yes I did the exact command. At first I added host public addr but I changed it to the private one because it's the one that works when pinging the machines. Do I still have to change it to public addr?

Comment: @issrae: Machine 1 should be able to connect with Machine 2 on its exposed <ip:port> where fluentd is listening for logs. `ping` may not work in some cases if it's disabled by policy but `telnet` should work from Machine 1 to Machine 2 because `forward` input plugin needs connectivity via TCP.

Comment: Fluentd gets the logs now it works, I had to run the container with the right port 24224, not the one in the documentation I followed, this way when I curl  0.0.0.0:24224 it connects. Thank you for taking time to help me :)

Comment: @issrae: Good to hear that. Well done! You're welcome! :)